# Sliced projections with Spring Data MongoDB ReactiveMongoRepository?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I have a collection named `myCollection` that contains documents with the following format:

```
{
    "_id" : "1",
    "myArray" : [ { x: 1, y: "a" }, { x: 2, y: "b" }, { x: 3, y: "c" }, { x: 4, y: "d" }, { x: 5, y: "e" }]
}
```

What I'd like to do is to construct a query that returns a [slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) of some elements in `myArray` as a projection.

I.e. let's say that my document is defined like this:

```
@Document(collection = "myCollection")
data class MyDocument(@Id val myId : String, val myArray : List<MyItem>)
```

where `MyItem` is defined like this:

```
data class MyItem(val x: Int, val y: String)
```

Now I want to create a function that returns a list of `MyItem` given a certain offset and item count (or a "page") for a `MyDocument` with a specific id.

This is what I've tried (using [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)):

```
data class MyArrayProjection(val myArray: List<MyItem>)

interface MyRepository : ReactiveMongoRepository<MyDocument, String> {             
    fun findByMyId(myId: String, pageable: Pageable): Flux<MyArrayProjection>
}
```

What I'd like to see when calling this function with e.g.

```
myRepository.findByMyId("1", PageRequest.of(1, 2))
```

is that it returns a `Flux` containing `MyItem(x=3, y="c")` and `MyItem(x=4, y="d")` but instead it's empty.

The generated MongoDB query looks like this:

```
{
    "find" : "myCollection",
    "filter" : {
        "_id" : "1"
    },
    "projection" : {
        "myArray" : 1
    },
    "skip" : 2,
    "limit" : 2,
    "batchSize" : 256
}
```

What I suspect is happening is that the `Pageable` instance operates on the aggregate (`MyDocument`) and not "inside" the `myArray` field which is why I suspect that I want to somehow use the [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) operator instead.

How can I achieve this? If it won't work using the [ReactiveMongoRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/ReactiveMongoRepository.html) then I'm fine with using [ReactiveMongoOperations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/ReactiveMongoOperations.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by changing:

```
interface MyRepository : ReactiveMongoRepository<MyDocument, String> {             
    fun findByMyId(myId: String, pageable: Pageable): Flux<MyArrayProjection>
}
```

to:

```
interface MyRepository : ReactiveMongoRepository<MyDocument, String> {             
    @Query(value = "{ '_id' : ?0 }", fields = "{ 'myArray': { '\$slice': ?1 } }")
    fun findByMyId(myId: String, slice: Array<Int>): Flux<MyArrayProjection>
}
```

and then call it using:

```
myRepository.findByMyId("1", arrayOf(1, 2))
```